# What is a development environment and how do I set it up?

Tags: node.js, development-environment

I'm looking at nodepad:
http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/15/node-tutorial-3/

And they have different development environments, development, staging, production.

How do I configure my server appropriately so that the app would know what environment it's supposed to be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [express framework documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration):

> To alter the environment we can set the NODE_ENV environment variable, for example:
>   `$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js`